# Syntax for structure dereference operator (->) with array subscript operator ([])

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this composition:

```
class Dataset
{
  std::unique_ptr<Properties> properties;
  std::unique_ptr<Properties> & getProperties() { return properties; }

  Dataset & getDataset() { return *this }
  ....
}

class Properties
{
  Property & operator[](const std::string & s);
  ...
}
```

How do I call the operator[]?  And why is the following a syntax error?

`getDataset().getProperties()->["Key"]`
// syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getDataset().getProperties()->operator[]("Key");
```

or

```
(*getDataset().getProperties())["Key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer:

```
(*getDataset().getProperties())["Key"];
```

Comment: `getDataset().getProperties()` is a `std::unique_ptr` so you have to have another dereferencing operation before calling `operator[]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches

```
( *getDataset().getProperties() )["Key"]

getDataset().getProperties()->operator []( "Key" )
```